# How to download file from google cloud bucket if there is a space within a folder name?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have successfully downloaded other files with no space within the folder name.
May I know how to type the file name if there is a space in the folder name?

i have tried to put in :

gsutil cp -r gs://picture_patrick/2016-travel C:\Users\werca

gsutil cp -r gs://picture_patrick/2016 travel C:\Users\werca

gsutil cp -r gs://picture_patrick/2016_travel C:\Users\werca

All shown "CommandException: No URLs matched"

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [Storage naming conventions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets) spaces are not valid for naming either buckets or objects. You should avoid special characters at all.

I would recommend you access manually your bucket and rename your file if possible because you won’t be able to interact with your object via gsutil tools if it contains a space in the name.